# Why `setup.py install` does not update the script file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, setuptools, setup.py

In the `setup.py` file, I write like this:

```
from distutils.core import setup
setup(
    # skip a lot of information here..
    scripts = ["chilin2/ChiLin2.py"],
)
```

I've setup my package successfully at first time. After a while I update the `line 209` of the script into this:

```
$ sed -n 209p chilin2/ChiLin2.py
        macs2_on_merged.param["control_opt"] = "-c " + macs2_on_merged.input["control"]
```

And then run `setup.py` again

```
$ sudo python3 setup.py install
running install
running build
running build_py
running build_scripts
running install_lib
running install_scripts
changing mode of /usr/local/bin/ChiLin2.py to 755
running install_egg_info
Removing /usr/local/lib/python3.2/site-packages/chilin2-0.1-py3.2.egg-info
Writing /usr/local/lib/python3.2/site-packages/chilin2-0.1-py3.2.egg-info
```

However, I found that the script file hasn't been changed..

```
$ sed -n 209p /usr/local/bin/ChiLin2.py
        macs2_on_merged["control_opt"] = "-c " + macs2_on_merged.input["control"]
```

I tried `setup.py clean` and then `setup.py install` again, but that doesn't solve the problem. Does anyone have ideas about this?

( I found that the `Chilin2.py` in the package has an elder time stamp than that in system directory. Is that the reason that `setup.py install` doesn't update? Is there a way to solve this? )

Comment: At first I thought this was http://bugs.python.org/issue10374 but that bug is different.

Comment: I have the same thing. I changed a function, I uninstalled the package, deleted all __pycache__ directories. But a function from an older version is used after reinstalling the package.

Comment: Same problem here, did you manage to find a solution?

Comment: Same problem in 2020.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to uninstall this package and then reinstall it.

pip can uninstall a package :

```
pip uninstall *packagename*
```

Answer (score 1):

> I found that the Chilin2.py in the package has an elder time stamp than that in system directory.

This is strange.  Can you reproduce the bug with these steps:

1. Create script.
2. setup.py install (with an --install or --user option to avoid sudo)
3. Edit script.
4. setup.py install
5. ?

If you did that (i.e. you edited the script after its first installation), I don’t understand how the latest script can have a modification time that is older than the installed script.

> Is that the reason that setup.py install doesn't update?

Definitely: distutils compares file modification times to see if it needs to re-build (for scripts, the build phase consists of copying the files to a temp build dir and adjusting the shebangs).

> Is there a way to solve this?

```
$ touch chilin2/ChiLin2.py
```